# Export text field with newlines

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a text field in my PostgreSQL database that contains newlines.  I want to export that field verbatim into a text file.  However, I can't figure out how to export the field without the newlines being encoded as `\n`.

Currently I'm just using `\copy` and manually doing a search-and-replace on `\n` in a text editor.

Comment: How do you write the text file?

Comment: You can't export a field verbatim.  It is currently in PostgreSQL's internal format, and once exported it will not be, so some kind of change is inevitable.  Otherwise, you wouldn't be wanting an export at all, you would be wanting a copy of PostgreSQL's data directory.  Try describing what you do want, rather than what you don't want.

Comment: @jjanes, the text field contains an XML document, which I'd like to open in my local IDE.  So I want to get that XML document out of the database and into a text file on my computer.  By "verbatim" I just mean no escape newlines or quotes or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first job of COPY is produce output that can be accurately reloaded.  But it sounds like you want the opposite, you want to produce output where you can't know by looking at it how the lines where originally grouped into records.

So you will most likely have to do some kind of post-processing.  You can use the text output format and change the \n to literal newlines, or you can use the csv output format and then remove the quote marks.  In both cases, there might be other escaped/quoted special characters that will also have to be dealt with.

An alternative would be break up the data before the COPY rather than after:

```
\COPY (select unnest(string_to_array(col1,E'\n')) from foo) TO ...
```